# Error starting protocol stack

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I am doing a tutorial and I get the following message.

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30334: bind: Only
>   one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted.

I started the Node with:

> bootnode -nodekey masternode.key -verbosity 9 -addr :30333 INFO
>   [09-04|05:47:38.287] UDP listener up
>   self=enode://98b3ea03edd9d500313466467dc0178ac107c0c3ac529e21abfc9586f6886c98b7e5bcd0b2de27ee4c99cce6b53ef1cad7f4a9934275d8b611dfb96061a76abe@[::]:30333

Then I start my first signer.

> geth --datadir signer1/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30334 --rpc
>   --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8544 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,clique' --bootnodes
>   'enode://98b3ea03edd9d500313466467dc0178ac107c0c3ac529e21abfc9586f6886c98b7e5bcd0b2de27ee4c99cce6b53ef1cad7f4a9934275d8b611dfb96061a76abe@127.0.0.1:30333'
>   --networkid 3131 --gasprice '1' -unlock '08f8e3a8db8d4d2611d524188391b689b3b6ee00' --password
>   signer1/passphrase.txt --mine

On to the second signer.

> geth --datadir signer2/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30334 --rpc
>   --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr 'localhost' --rpcport 8544 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,clique' --bootnodes
>   'enode://98b3ea03edd9d500313466467dc0178ac107c0c3ac529e21abfc9586f6886c98b7e5bcd0b2de27ee4c99cce6b53ef1cad7f4a9934275d8b611dfb96061a76abe@127.0.0.1:30333'
>   --networkid 3131 --gasprice '1' -unlock '939fb51695c7b8892382ec253475c580377ecbd9' --password
>   signer2/passphrase.txt --mine

As far as I understand they should listen to the same ports but I get an error instead.

I am using Windows 10.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

On the second signer change the port number to:

```
--port 30335
```

Only one process can bind to a certain port number , this is the way operating systems were designed.

Also, what you're calling a "signer" is actually called "node", and what you are calling a "node" is called "bootnode".